# CELERYD_OPTS configuration

Tags: celery

I have following configuration in /etc/default/celeryd

```
CELERYD_NODES = "worker1 worker2 worker3"
CELERYD_CHDIR = "path to project dir"
CELERY_APP = "path to project app"
CELERYD_OPTS = ""
```

I want all my three workers to consume task from different queues
say Q1, Q2 and Q3.

I'm not able to understand the config to put in CELERYD_OPTS.
I've gone through http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html#examples

But no help.

Answer (score 4):

I should have searched for some more.
Finally answer found by my sir.

```
CELERYD_OPTS = "-Q:worker1 Q1 -Q:worker2 Q2 -Q:worker3 Q3 -Q:worker4 Q3"
```

This assings worker1 to Q1, worker2 to Q2 and so on.

Comment: CELERYD_OPTS = "-Q:worker1 Q1 -Q:worker2 Q1 -Q:worker3 Q1 -Q:worker4 Q2"

This is what seems to me your answer.